# RewriteRule not working on production server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

For my current project I have to Redirect 301 some links but when you enter them with some extra get parameters that parameters need to be suffixed on the new url.

Example:

Old:
/language/nl/article-1/?test=123

new:
/language/nl/fa1-artcile-1/?test=123

So I use the following code: (which works fine on my dev env)

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /language/nl
RewriteRule /artcile-1/*    /language/nl/fa1-artcile-1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But once on my production env it does not work, it still redirects to new url but, the get parameters are not appended on the new url.

**Edit: It does redirect but it does not append the parameters.**

Edit 2: full fill

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The rewrite rule(s) come before the wordpress part and I have about 30 of them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that rewriting is enabled and htaccess is allowed on your Production?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the rule works but only the parameters are not appended on my production server.

Comment: @anubhava it's a Wordpress site, the file is placed in the root.

Comment: ok can you show your full .htaccess in that case

Comment: Have you tried using the QSA flag (Query String Append) [R=301,QSA,L]

Comment: Updated my first post. @Tristan I'm going to try that right now!

Answer (score 1):

Have it like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^language/nl/article-1/?$ /language/nl/fa1-artcile-1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: This would probaly work but for my case it will not, just discover we are running this on a MS Azure env. We need a web.config file.

Comment: Hmm then how come you have working htaccess for wordpress

Comment: Apparently rewrite rules just don't work, but redirects 301 etc work just like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the [query string](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the other answers here are correct as well. But for my case they won't work.

The env it is running up is a MS Azure env, so I need to have a web.config file instead of a .htaccess file (how ever, it works for some part).

Thanks for all the quick help and thinking!